# How many graphs on n nodes, with each component a coherently directed tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For a positive integer $n$ choose $m$ with $1 \le m \le n$ and let $X$ be a set with $|X|=n$. choose $x_j \in X$ for $j=1,...,m$.

Define $m$ directed graphs $X_j$ in the following way:

Initially we have for each $j$:
$$
X_j =\{x_j\}
$$
if (as sets)
$$
\cup_j X_j = X
$$
then we are done. otherwise choose $x \in X-\cup_j X_j$ and choose $k$ with $1 \le k \le m$. take $y \in X_k$ and add $y$ to the nodeset of $X_k$. then add a single arc directed from $y$ to some other element of $X_k$.

at the termination of this procedure we have partitioned $X$ into disjoint sets $X_j$ and have given each $X_j$ the additional structure of a directed tree with root $x_j$.

**Question** how many ways are there of doing this?

Motivation: this came out of thinking about the structure of endomorphisms of a finite set. for a partition into trees along the lines indicated, every permutation $\sigma \in S_m$ of the set $\{x_j\}$ allows us to define an endomorphism of X as follows:
$ \forall x_j $ add the arc joining $x_j$ to $\sigma(x_j)$. every node of the resulting graph now has out-degree $1$.

My hypothesis is that every endomorphism may be represented as a unique graph as described. thus if $T_{n,m}$ is the number of way of partitioning a set of $n$ elements into $m$ directed trees, then we have:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n T_{n,m} m! = n^n
$$